# Trying to use a JWT to access an API from my flutter app that will hold details from my MySQL database

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I have added a login function for my flutter app that will create a JWT token on a successful login. The problem I run into is when I try to decode this JWT to access my API for the app. I get a couple of different errors mainly "'kid' empty, unable to lookup correct key" or "signature verification failed". I understand that there are similar questions that have been asked on this but nothing has worked. Could someone look at my code and suggest where I am going wrong in the decoding process. I have attached three pieces of code. The first is the login_access.php file. This has been successful in making the JWT on logging in and I have been able to save it in shared preferences, as I can see it in the print to console statements. I think the problem is in the third piece of code, which is the API that is supposed to supply data from the database on successful verification of the JWT. Again, I apologise if this has been asked but I am fairly new to this and nothing I do seems to work.

```
// Generate and return JWT access token
$tokenId = base64_encode(random_bytes(32));
$issuedAt = time();
$notBefore = $issuedAt;
$expire = $notBefore + 3600; // The token will be valid for 1 hour
$serverName = "http://tocathain01.webhosting6.eeecs.qub.ac.uk";

$data = [
  'iat' => $issuedAt,        // Issued at
  'jti' => $tokenId,         // Token ID
  'iss' => $serverName,      // Issuer
  'nbf' => $notBefore,       // Not before
  'exp' => $expire,          // Expiration
  'data' => [                // Data related to the patient
    'patientId' => $patient['patient_id']
  ]
];

//create header to base64Url format
$header = [
    'alg' => 'HS256',
    'typ' => 'JWT',
    'kid' => 'your_key_id'
];

$secretKey = 'secretkey1544'; // Replace with your JWT secret key
$algorithm = 'HS256';
$jwt = JWT::encode($data, $secretKey, $algorithm, null, $header);

// Return the access token
header('Content-Type: application/json');
http_response_code(200);
echo json_encode([
  'status' => 'success',
  'token' => $jwt
]);

} else {
//Invalid login attempt

header('Content-Type: application/json');

http_response_code(401);

echo json_encode([
'status' => 'error',
'message' => 'Invalid email or password'
]);

}

$stmt-\>close();
$conn-\>close();
}
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:patients_remotecare_app/ui/models/doctor.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

Future<Doctor> getDoctor() async {
  final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  final token = prefs.getString('token');
  print('Token retrieved from SharedPreferences: $token');

  final response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(
        'http://tocathain01.webhosting6.eeecs.qub.ac.uk/api/appapi/doctor/doctor_data.php'),
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
    },
  );
  print("String");
  print('Response body : ${response.body}');
  print('${response.statusCode}');
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    print(
        'Decoded JSON data: $data'); // Add this line to print the decoded JSON data
    return Doctor.fromJson(data);
  } else {
    final data = json.decode(response.body);
    print('Decode Json data: $data');
    throw Exception('Failed to load doctor details');
  }
}
```

```
<?php
include '../vendor/autoload.php';
// Requires: composer require firebase/php-jwt
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

$headers = apache_request_headers();
// }
// Fix missing Authorization header for some server configurations
if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = $headers['Authorization'];
} elseif (isset($headers['authorization'])) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = $headers['authorization'];
}


$authHeader = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
echo "$authHeader";
$jwt = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $authHeader); // Remove "Bearer " from the header value

// Get the access token from the request headers
if (function_exists('getallheaders')) {
    $headers = getallheaders();
} else {
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
}
// error_log("Headers: " . print_r($headers, true));
$access_token = '';

foreach ($headers as $key => $value) {
    if (strtolower($key) == 'authorization') {
        $access_token = str_replace('Bearer ', '', $value);
        break;
    }
}
error_log("Access token: " . $access_token);
// Verify the access token
try {
    $secretKey = base64_encode('secretkey1544');
    $algorithm = 'HS256';

    $decoded = JWT::decode($access_token, new Key($secretKey, $algorithm));
    // $decoded = JWT::decode($jwt, $secretKey, [$algorithm]);
    $userId = $decoded->data->userId;

    // Query the database to get the patients for the authenticated doctor

    include('../../conn_online.php');

    $doctor_sql = "SELECT doctor_id FROM patient WHERE patient_id = ?";
    $select_doctor_stmt = $conn->prepare($doctor_sql);
    $select_doctor_stmt->bind_param("i", $userId);
    $select_doctor_stmt->execute();
    $result = $select_doctor_stmt->get_result();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $doctor_id_row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $doctor_id = $doctor_id_row["doctor_id"];
    }

    $select_doctor_info = "SELECT * FROM doctor WHERE doctor_id = ?";
    $select_doctor_info_stmt = $conn->prepare($select_doctor_info);
    $select_doctor_info_stmt->bind_param("i", $doctor_id);
    $select_doctor_info_stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $select_doctor_info_stmt->get_result();

    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        $doctor_info = $result2->fetch_assoc();

        // Return the doctor information as JSON
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($doctor_info);
    } else {
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        http_response_code(404);
        echo json_encode([
            'status' => 'error',
            'message' => 'Doctor not found'
        ]);
    }
    $select_doctor_stmt->close();
    $select_doctor_info_stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    // Invalid access token
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    http_response_code(401);
    error_log("Exception: " . $e);
    echo json_encode([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
}
```